# Gráfico em árvore do plotly mostrando valores errados em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gráfico, plotly

Esse gŕafico [sunburst](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#sunburst-of-a-rectangular-dataframe-with-continuous-color-argument-in-pxsunburst) do plotly, quando usado em um dataframe desta [planilha](https://ibb.co/S5k9s09), através do código abaixo, gera um gráfico valores errados da coluna 'resto'. Por exemplo, no caminho 'despesa/servico/eletricidade', na planilha, o gráfico deveria mostrar sob a variável 'resto' a soma de 299 e 49, que são os valores na planilha sob a coluna 'resto' que correspondem ao caminho mencionado. Mas ele mostra um valor [errado](https://ibb.co/MPskcxv), 263.287(...). O mesmo erro se repete em vários caminhos, e não só nesse.

Acredito que o código abaixo não esteja pedindo para que o valor correspondente a cor ( representado pela coluna 'resto') tenha seu valor definido pela soma de todas as células nesta coluna ('resto') e caminho ( por exemplo 'despesa/servico/eletricidade'). Deve estar fazendo algum outro cálculo que não identifiquei ... E deve ter uma forma de pedir para somar, mas não sei como.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('vai.csv')
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['renda_despesa','categoria1', 'categoria2','categoria3'], values='teto',
                          color='resto', hover_data=['categoria3'],
                          color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                          color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['resto'], weights=df['teto']),
                          branchvalues="total")    
fig.show()
```